# Command not found -sh: shell script error

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script to extract a date value from header of the input file, but it is failing with command not found error:
Could you please guide me here

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f input.txt ]; then
    echo "FILE exists."
    Header_date = $(cut -c8-25 input.txt | head -1)
    echo -e " header date value is : $Header_date"
else 
    echo "$FILE does not exist."
fi
```

error:

```
FILE exists.
-sh: Header_date: command not found
 header date value is :
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces before and after `=` on line `Header_date = $(cut -c8-25 input.txt | head -1)` are not allowed